# screen crash (not black screen) after suspending my HP Laptop on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, graphics, suspend

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on my HP 15-ak001ns and resuming the laptop after suspending (closing the lid or suspending via the interface) results in  a screen full of colors (every pixel a different color).
[See this image of the crashed screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAw5i.jpg)

[image]
I've looked online for this problem but everybody else has a black screen problem which is not my case (but might be related?). The mouse works and it's over this colored error.

I used to have Ubuntu 16 on this machine but I eventually swapped for Windows, and now Ubuntu again. With Ubuntu 16 I didn't have this problem so maybe it's either Ubuntu 18 or I installed something wrong.

Also this machine has an Nvidia GTX 950M which is set as the primary display with the proprietary drivers and the Intel integrated graphics card.

I have no idea how to debug this problem since I'm not at all an expert on Ubuntu. Any help is welcome as I really want to take my laptop with me in class and suspend and resume at any time.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Try the following: press ctrl+alt+f3 , this should get you into a TTY interface, then press ctrl+alt+f2 or f1 to get back to your desktop / login screen. and tell us if this fixes it. Does the same happen when you freshly boot up?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting! Sadly ctrl+alt+F1-12 doesn't work. It just doesn't change anything but I haven't bothered fixing this since I haven't had the need to use it, until now I guess. I'll look into fixing and trying to ctrl+alt+fn.

Comment: Well this was just a guess since i saw a similar pattern already on 16.04 maybe one of the other people here has an answer for you.

Comment: Do you happen to know more places where I can ask for help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. I had a swap partition which was cousing both the Ctrl+Alt+F1-12 problems and the recovery from suspension colorful screen crash. I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, deleted the swap partition in the installation and it now works.

I've got to say I've gotten pretty desperate. I chatted with Nvidia about their drivers, I tried to upgrade the proprietary drivers from 390 to 396 and somehow screwed up everything (nividia-settings wouldn't open up). I have even come close to install windows in order to update the BIOS and the motherboard chipset to see if it helped. Glad to know it was this, no idea why though...

Thanks for the help anyways! Go FOSS.